# React Material UI Toggle Switch in Loop with Database Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to use a material UI switch to update Active & De-Active in the database from the list of users from the Admin Panel.

Currently, All Database update is working fine on the toggle switch. but switch status/colour is not updating. And If we click on one all switch is toggling.

Problem: Whenever I click on switch all switch is toggling and the correct value updated in the database.  After that, I need to refresh the page to reflect changes.

[image]

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: false,
  });
```

```
  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
    console.log(state);
    const userId = event.target.id;

    if (event.target.checked) {
      const status = 1;

      axios({
        method: "get",
        baseURL: `${baseURL}`,
        url: `activeDeactiveUser/${status}/${userId}`,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      const status = 0;
      const userId = event.target.id;
      axios({
        method: "get",
        baseURL: `${baseURL}`,
        url: `activeDeactiveUser/${status}/${userId}`,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };
```

```
        filteredData.map((userdata, index) => (
                      <tr key={userdata.mytag_user_id}>
                
                        <td>
                          {userdata.is_active === 1 ? (
                            <Switch
                              checked={state.checkedA}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                              name="checkedA"
                              id={userdata.mytag_user_id}
                              inputProps={{
                                "aria-label": "secondary checkbox",
                              }}
                            />
                          ) : (
                            <Switch
                              checked={state.checkedB}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                              name="checkedB"
                              id={userdata.mytag_user_id}
                              inputProps={{
                                "aria-label": "secondary checkbox",
                              }}
                            />
                          )}

                          {userdata.is_active}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Link to={`/user/${userdata.mytag_user_id}`}>
                            View Profile
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))
```

Comment: You are not setting `checked` based on a database value. It's just a local state shared between all switches

Comment: how to set `checked` ? @TJ

Comment: Should be something like `userdata.active`

Comment: I think I have already set active de-active value based on database value like if `is_Active == 1` `checked` value `state.checkedA` means colour  @TJ

Comment: `userdata.is_active` is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by refreshing

`const [refreash, setRefreash] = useState(false);`

```
  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });

    const userId = event.target.id;

    if (event.target.checked) {
      const status = 1;

      axios({
        method: "get",
        baseURL: `${baseURL}`,
        url: `activeDeactiveUser/${status}/${userId}`,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          setRefreash(!refreash);
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      const status = 0;
      const userId = event.target.id;
      axios({
        method: "get",
        baseURL: `${baseURL}`,
        url: `activeDeactiveUser/${status}/${userId}`,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          setRefreash(!refreash);
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };
```

```
  const fetch_user = () => {
    axios({
      method: "get",

      baseURL: `${baseUrl}`,
      url: "users",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        //   setData(response.data);
        const data = response.data;
        // setIsLoading(false);
        if (data.success == 1) {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setSuccess(1);
          setData(data.data);
          console.log(data);
        } else {
          setSuccess(0);
        }
        //   console.log(response.data.success);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch_user();
  }, [refreash]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`state.checkedA` and `state.checkedB` are shared with all toggles. They need separate (individual) state or they toggle together.

Modify the JSX to:

```
<td>
  <Switch 
     checked={userdata.is_active === 1}
     onChange={handleChange}
     name="checkedA" id={userdata.mytag_user_id}
     inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox", }} />
</td>
```

And update your `handleChange` function to update the `is_active` of that user to `0` (change this line: `setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });`) accordingly.

Comment: What to change in `setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });` ? @TJ

Comment: You need to find the toggled used and update the `is_active` of that user to `0`